# I need to know how to copy a c-string from one varible to another in order to get a third function to work in my program

Tags: c++, string, function

I'm trying to write three functions for an assignment

- `changeUp` changes a string to uppercase
- `changeDown` changes a string to lowercase
- `changeRev` reverses the case of each character

Each function must accept *a pointer to a string or C-string* as an argument and must make the changes above by iterating over each character in the input string.

When entering `AbCd`, the first function should return `ABCD`; the second function should return `abcd`; and the reverse function should return `aBcD`.

I cannot figure out how to get the last function to work - it just returns all uppercase letters.

I have tried copying the input to a variable to save it - you can see my commented out areas where I tried to do this, but I really don't know what I'm doing, I'll just be honest.  I got all kinds of errors when trying to copy (line, line2).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

void changeUp(char *line)//Change to upper case
{
    for (int i = 0; line[i]; i++)
    {
        if (islower(line[i])) line[i] = toupper(line[i]);

    }
}

void changeDown(char *line)//Change to lower case
{
    for (int i = 0; line[i]; i++)
    {
            if (isupper(line[i])) line[i] = tolower(line[i]);
    }
}

void changeRev(char *line)//Reverse the cases
{
    for (int i = 0; line[i]; i++)
    {
        if (isupper(line[i])) line[i] = tolower(line[i]);
        else if (islower(line[i]))  line[i] = toupper(line[i]);
    }
} 

void main()
{
    const int SIZE = 81; //For character space
    char line[SIZE], line2[SIZE];//Character array

    cout << "Enter a string  of characters :" <<endl;//Takestring       input from user
    cin.getline(line, SIZE);


    //strcpy_s(line, line2);
    changeUp(line);
    cout << "Changed to Upper Case " << line << endl;//Output string in all caps


    //strcpy_s(line, line2);
    changeDown(line);
    cout << "Changed to Lower Case " << line << endl;//Output string in lower case

    //strcpy_s(line, line2);
    changeRev(line);
    cout << "The rverse of the characters is " << line << endl;//Output     reverse of string entered
    system("pause");
    return;
 }
```

Comment: Please don't post code with `void main()`. That's non-standard and won't compile with most compilers. I fixed that for you now. Similarly please don't post code that needlessly uses non-standard headers such as `<stdafx.h>`. These cannot be as easily removed, because the code may depend on their content, and they prevent readers from trying out your code.

Comment: `strcpy_s(line2, line);`?

Comment: Do you understand why the `changeRev` function appears not to work? Do you see how you could solve the problem by copying the input line-- if you knew how to copy a line? *Which problem are you trying to solve?*

Comment: @Beta-I knew why it wasn't working and I was getting the opposite of the changeDown function, but didn't know how to correct it.  That is what I was trying to solve-copying the input line.  I am in my 2nd semester of C++ programming with absolutely no prior experience.  What seems like something so easy isn't so to me.

Comment: @Alf-I go by what my instructor tells me to do.  He sets his up with void main().  <stdafx.h> is a required header with visual studio Win32ConsoleApplication, which I am required to use.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.  The problem is that you are operating on the same variable and are overwriting the input `line` each time you run your functions on it.  When you run `changeRev` you are "reversing" the result of the input string after you have just modified it to lowercase using `changeDown`.   Reversing this string naturally makes it all uppercase.

Creating a copy is the right thing to do, but **you have have just gotten the order of the arguments wrong**. The destination is first, the source second.  Then make sure to only operate on the copy, `line2` so that the user's original input remains unmodified in the `line` variable so that you can use it again later.

```
strcpy_s(line2, line);
changeUp(line2);
cout << "Changed to Upper Case " << line2 << endl;/


strcpy_s(line2, line);
changeDown(line2);
cout << "Changed to Lower Case " << line2 << endl;

strcpy_s(line2, line);
changeRev(line2);
cout << "The reverse of the characters is " << line2 << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!  I knew it had to be something simple, but I just couldn't get it.  That did it!

Comment: @Jesse Good - now take from this the lesson that you should always [*read the documentation*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) when you're not sure about things.  Stepping through with a debugger can often help with the rest. ;)

Comment: @J...: An even more important lesson is to *develop new functionality in isolation* as much as possible. You wanted to copy a string; you tried to copy a string in the context of a big, malfunctioning program. If you had hard-coded two strings, tried to copy one into the other and then printed them both, you would have cracked the problem in two minutes (even if the documentation had been wrong, as it occasionally is).

Comment: @Beta Point, and point.  One thing at a time and test, test, test!

Answer (score 1):

it is bad practice to include: "using namespace std", it is better to use std::cout and that goes for all functions from that namespace. Also you were sending a pointer to function so each time each function was modifying the string, therefore before your reverse condition you were passing all lowercase therefore that is why you were getting all caps. I think something like the solution bellow would be better approach.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

string changeUp(string line)//Change to upper case
{
    for (int i = 0; line[i]; i++)
    {
        if (islower(line[i])) line[i] = toupper(line[i]);

    }

    return line;
}

string changeDown(string line)//Change to lower case
{
    for (int i = 0; line[i]; i++)
    {
        if (isupper(line[i])) line[i] = tolower(line[i]);
    }

    return line;
}

string changeRev(string line)//Reverse the cases
{
    for (int i = 0; line[i]; i++)
    {
        if (isupper(line[i])) line[i] = tolower(line[i]);
        else if (islower(line[i]))  line[i] = toupper(line[i]);
    }
    return line;
}

void main()
{
    const int SIZE = 81; //For character space
    char line[SIZE], line2[SIZE];//Character array

    cout << "Enter a string  of characters :" << endl;//Takestring       input from user
    cin.getline(line, SIZE);


    //strcpy_s(line, line2);

    cout << "Changed to Upper Case " << changeUp(line) << endl;//Output string in all caps


    //strcpy_s(line, line2);

    cout << "Changed to Lower Case " << changeDown(line) << endl;//Output string in lower case

    //strcpy_s(line, line2);
    cout << "The rverse of the characters is " << changeRev(line) << endl;//Output     reverse of string entered
    system("pause");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I heavily edited OP's rambling original question and omitted one important detail - namely that these functions must accept a pointer to a string and not a plain string.  My fault...

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the functions are modifying the string in-place. Hence the string goes from `AbCd` => `ABCD` => `abcd` => `ABCD`. You lose the original string in the first call.

The solution is to make a copy of the string every time and call the function on the copy.